# How to specify current working directory for project-level `.npmrc`?

Tags: npm

An absolute path, as shown below, works, but I need `npm` to use a relative path from the directory of the `.npmrc` file (the current working directory for the project), instead of the absolute path.

How to specify the relative path (instead of writing out the absolute path), or if it's not that simple, how to set things up?

Absolute path used in `<some-project>/.npmrc`:

`onload-script = /some-absoloute-path/some-node-module.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [npmrc documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc):

> Environment variables can be replaced using ${VARIABLE_NAME}. For example:

```
prefix = ${HOME}/.npm-packages
```

For your case, you can use the `$PWD` environment variable, which gives the current directory:

```
onload-script = ${PWD}/some-relative-path/some-node-module.js
```

Comment: Any solution for cross-platform projects? (Windows does not have PWD, Linux does not have CD)

Comment: Define your own environment variable (e.g. PREFIX) within your OS. And use it inside `.npmrc`.

Comment: This requires manual configuration of each workstation, I could use a cross-platform solution for `.npmrc` relying on modifying the shared git repository alone.

Comment: I'm with @Elad on this. Did you find any solution since?

Comment: Also looking for a cross platform solution